# PHP adding empty rows to MySQL

Tags: php

I have a textarea which is going to be post to PHP.

In the PHP script, I will explode the textarea by newline.

Then, I will make a loop to iterate the array to check if the value already exist in the MySQL or not. If it already exist, then I will do a continue, else I will do an insert.

This is how my code looks like:

```
$route = $_POST['gatewayvalue'];
$account_number = $_POST['account_number'];
$route = strtoupper($route);

$routelist = explode("\n", $route);
$count = count($routelist);
$invalid = 0;

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
if(preg_match("/000F26/i", $routelist[$i])){
    $routeinsert = str_replace("000F26", "", $routelist[$i]);

    $verify = "SELECT route FROM gw_gateway WHERE route='$routeinsert'";
    $result = mysql_query($verify);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $checkroute = $row['route'];
    if($checkroute == $routeinsert){
        $validate = false;

        $invalid++;

        continue;
    }
    else{
        $validate = true;
    }
}
else{
    $routeinsert = $routelist[$i];

    $verify = "SELECT route FROM gw_gateway WHERE route='$routeinsert'";
    $result = mysql_query($verify);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $checkroute = $row['route'];
    if($checkroute == $routeinsert){
        $validate = false;

        $invalid++;

        continue;
    }
    else{
        $validate = true;
    }
}

if($validate == true){
    $updateroutesql = "INSERT INTO gw_gateway SET route='$routeinsert', gw_reseller1='$account_number'";
    $updateroutesqlres=mysql_query($updateroutesql) or die("Can not perform update query !".mysql_error());
}
}
```

However, when I insert 2 similar values, for example, 030301 twice in the textarea.
The 1st value will be rejected, but the 2nd value will be inserted as an empty value.

My table has 3 fields.

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| route          | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| account_number | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gw_reseller1   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And this is what happened when I try to insert 2 similar values

```
+----------+----------------+--------------+
| route    | account_number | gw_reseller1 |
+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 030302   | NULL           | NULL         |
| NULL     | 201-000001     |              |
| 030301   | NULL           | 201-000001   |
+----------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: How can your primary key could be inserted a `NULL` value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to shorten Your code. You have the same code parts twice which is useless...
Then, sanitize Your input.
Finaly, move on with `PDO` or at least `mysqli_*` functions as `mysql_*` is deprecated now.

New code:

```
$route = strtoupper($_POST['gatewayvalue']);
$account_number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['account_number']);

$routelist = explode("\n", $route);
$count = count($routelist);
$invalid = 0;

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if(preg_match("/000F26/i", $routelist[$i])){
        $routeinsert = str_replace("000F26", "", $routelist[$i]);
    } else {
        $routeinsert = $routelist[$i];
    }

    $verify = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM gw_gateway WHERE route='" . mysql_real_escape_string($routeinsert) . "' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($verify) || !trim($routeinsert)) { // if the route is present in DB mysql_num_rows will return 1 row, or when $routeinsert is an empty string - continue...
        $invalid++;

        continue;
    } else {
        $updateroutesql = "INSERT INTO gw_gateway SET route='" . mysql_real_escape_string($routeinsert) . "', gw_reseller1='$account_number'";
        $updateroutesqlres=mysql_query($updateroutesql) or die("Can not perform update query !".mysql_error());
    }

}
```

Try this edited code - should be OK. If there is still some value inserted as null or empty it means that You have typed an empty line in the textarea and You should also check for the route not to be empty when inserting...

Comment: Your way was the closest to solving my issue. I just had to add this line $routeinsert = trim($routeinsert);
Now it won't insert if I try to insert 2 similar value in the textarea.

Comment: Also mind the code shortening - sometimes a minute or two more thinking will result in 30 minute less coding... It is not always true the more code lines the more powerfull the application... You are welcome!

Comment: Yea... I guess I need to improve on my code efficiency. I will take your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, this is the right way to insert data in the db:

```
$updateroutesql = "INSERT INTO gw_gateway (route,gw_reseller1) VALUES('".$routeinsert".','".$account_number."'";
```

But first, escape your strings (for security measures), like this:

```
$routeinsert = mysql_real_escape_string($routeinsert);
$account_number = mysql_real_escape_string($account_number);
```

Comment: Even with your suggestion, it is still adding with the empty route.

Comment: In MySQL, also `INSERT INTO [table] SET [column] = [value], ...` is available and very OK to use... The classic SQL way would be better or right way to use if there would be a chance he could change the DBMS (so switch from MySQL to ORACLE, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Due to primary key field when you second time insert same value it has been rejected coz it has been already inserted once.

Try with two differ values